When can we apply conservation of momentum in the presence of friction?
I often get confused about the concept of "external forces" in physics, especially when dealing with conservation of momentum and conservation of energy. In particular, I’ve seen problems where conservation of momentum is applied even though friction is present in the system.
My understanding is that conservation of momentum applies only when there is no net external force acting on the system. However, friction seems like it should be an external force in many cases, which would prevent momentum conservation. For instance, if two blocks slide on a rough surface and collide, how does friction affect the conservation of momentum for the system?
Could someone clarify:

What exactly qualifies as an "external force" in a system?
Under what conditions can conservation of momentum still be applied when friction is present?
How does the distinction between internal and external forces help in analyzing such problems?

I’d appreciate any examples or explanations that help clarify these concepts!

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/255990/ , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79884/ , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/466102/

The question to which you have been referred seems to have answers to your first and third questions. Regarding your second question, suppose that your system consists of two colliding cars. There will be frictional forces acting on the cars from the road surface. These are external forces on the system. However,  if we are concerned just with the immediate period of the impact (perhaps 1 or 2 seconds) these forces will be very small compared with the forces between the cars, and their effect on the cars' momenta and kinetic energies will be pretty much negligible.
